# REDUX на сервере - возможно ли это?

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер, клиент-сервер, redux

Применив Redux на клиентской части своего приложения, теперь не могу отделаться от навязчивой идеи сделать то же и на серверной. Вначале вдохновившись [этой статьей на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/company/mailru/blog/303456/#4-6) и едва начав изыскания на данную тему, пришлось признать бессмысленность единого хранилища состояний ввиду того, что всё пишется в базу данных, и предполагаемую [бессмысленность затеи в целом](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/437804/).

Нашелся вариант применения на сервере не Redux, но его принципов в виде CQRS и Event Sourcing - [описан здесь](https://medium.com/resolvejs/resolve-redux-backend-ebcfc79bbbea), но это еще сложнее, чем просто Redux, и вся эта сложность оправдана в основном в тех случаях, когда приложению нужно хранить историю изменений на сервере.

Быть может, у кого-нибудь есть опыт применения Redux в чистом виде на сервере? Или идеи на этой счет? статьи, примеры кода? Поделитесь, пожалуйста.

Comment: Просто привлекает возможность централизованной обработки действий в редьюсерах - удобно и наглядно, если, например, будет много клиентов, и всем им надо подписаться на изменения, приходящие на сервер (чат, форум и т.п). Мои мысли на тему - скажем, это RESTful API. На эндпойнт /users/ приходит POST-запрос на добавление нового юзера с данными этого юзера. Этот эндпойнт формирует action {type: ADD_USER, data: userData}. Далее action приходит на редьюсер, который пишет нового юзера в базу, и после этого всех юзеров из базы кладет в store.

Comment: ....Store обновляется, и store.subscribe(
    () => io.emit('SET_USERS', store.getState('users').toJS())
  ); всем клиентам отправляется новый список юзеров. И да, в этой схеме получается, что store нужен только для того, чтобы спровоцировать отправку клиентам, это можно сделать и без store. И вот никаким боком он не вписывается. А без store вроде как и Redux не Redux.

Comment: store - это состояние приложения. У вас в этом качестве выступает база данных. Смысла особого в redux на беке нету.